# How to generate a SQL Server Snapshot publication as a step of existing SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I'm thinking of setting up a Local Publication for a database in SQL Server 2017. Is it possbile to generate a Snapshot publication as part of an existing SQL Server Agent Job? There is a schedule when you use the "New publication Wizard" but this generates the snapshot at a specific time. I would need the Snapshot to be generated once one of the steps in an existing job completes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possbile to generate a Snapshot publication as part of an existing SQL Server Agent Job?

Sure.  Just let the wizard create a new agent job, and inspect its job steps.  You can then add similar steps to an existing job.  Or add a a TSQL job step to your existing job that kicks off the Replication job through [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I think sp_start_job is the way to go. If memory serves, replication keeps track of the job IDs for jobs it creates. So leaving those in place and starting them seems right to me.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for this. I wasn't aware of the sp_start_job